# Ruby: accessing a class constant for instance of class

Tags: ruby

I have a class that looks like the following:

```
class Foo
  MY_CONST = "hello"
  ANOTHER_CONST = "world"

  def self.get_my_const
    Object.const_get("ANOTHER_CONST")
  end
end

class Bar < Foo
  def do_something
    avar = Foo.get_my_const # errors here
  end
end
```

Getting a `const_get uninitialized constant ANOTHER_CONST (NameError)`

Assuming I'm just doing something silly in as far as Ruby scope goes. I'm currently using Ruby  1.9.3p0 on the machine where I'm testing this code.

Comment: You want to call `const_get` on `Foo`, not on `Object`. `Foo` inherits from `Object`, so it will respond to `const_get`, but you need to send the message to the object that can properly respond to it - which in this case is `Foo`, since that's the object on which the const is defined.

Comment: @ChrisHeald Exactly right!! Can I put it in my answer as you explained already,or leave it comment itself? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Now working:

```
class Foo
  MY_CONST = "hello"
  ANOTHER_CONST = "world"

  def self.get_my_const
    const_get("ANOTHER_CONST")
  end
end

class Bar < Foo
  def do_something
    avar = Foo.get_my_const
  end
end

Bar.new.do_something # => "world"
```

Your below part is not correct:

```
def self.get_my_const
    Object.const_get("ANOTHER_CONST")
end
```

Inside the method `get_my_const`,self is `Foo`. So remove `Object`,it will work..

Answer (score 3):

You can use const like:

```
Foo::MY_CONST
Foo::ANOTHER_CONST
```

You can gey a array of constants:

```
Foo.constants
Foo.constants.first
```

With your code:

```
class Foo
    MY_CONST = 'hello'

    def self.get_my_const
        Foo::MY_CONST
    end
end


class Bar < Foo
    def do_something
        avar = Foo.get_my_const
    end
end


x = Bar.new
x.do_something
```

Comment: I need to dynamically get the const from a string, hence why I'm using `Object.const_get`, so I need to be able to get it by calling a class instance method.

Comment: Just use `const_get const_name` then, since that will call `const_get` on `self` which will be your `Foo` class in that scope.

Comment: Okay,please put it inside the OP's code and let me know..This doesn't answer OP's actual post..

Comment: `def self.get_my_const
        Foo::MY_CONST
    end` needless.. only `MY_CONST` is enough..

Comment: @Rogier `x.do_something` wouldn't work..you need to write then `x = Bar.new`.. :)

Answer (score 3):

I recommend going through self `self.class.const_get("MY_CONST")` so you always get the correct constant.

```
class Foo
  MY_CONST = "hello"
  ANOTHER_CONST = "world"
end

class Bar < Foo
  MY_CONST = "hola"

  def do_something
    [self.class.const_get("MY_CONST"), self.class.const_get("ANOTHER_CONST")].join(' ')
  end
end

Bar.new.do_something #=> hola world
```